# Exponential mapping from a convex polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-exponential

I want to know whether the image of a convex polytope $\mathcal{M} \subseteq R^{n \times n}$ under the mapping $A \mapsto exp(\tau A)$ remains a convex polytope (not necessarily $\mathcal{M}$)?  Here $A \in \mathcal{M}(R^{n \times n})$ and $\tau > 0$ is known constant.

Further, what if the map is $A \mapsto Aexp(\tau A)$?

Thanks in advance. Structured explanation would help.

Comment: Does anybody got a better answer yet? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider the line segment between $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$ and let $\tau=1$. The image includes $\pmatrix{e&0\\0&1}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&e}$, but not the line segment between them, such as $\pmatrix{\frac{e+1}{2}&0\\0&\frac{e+1}{2}}$.

**Edit:** More explicitly: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the line segment between $a=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $b=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$. Let $f:A\mapsto\exp(A)$. Then $f(\mathcal{M})$ is **not convex**. Because: $$f(a)=\pmatrix{e&0\\0&1}\in f(\mathcal{M})$$
$$f(b)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&e}\in f(\mathcal{M})$$
But
$$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}=\pmatrix{\frac{e+1}{2}&0\\0&\frac{e+1}{2}}\not\in f(\mathcal{M}).$$

Comment: What do you mean by line segment between two matrices? Do you mean if $\lambda A + (1- \lambda) B \in \mathcal{M}$ where $A$ and $B$ are two end point matrices, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then $\lambda exp(A) + (1- \lambda) exp(B) \notin \mathcal{M}$? What is the $\lambda$ in the example?

Comment: Yes, in this example, $\lambda=1/2$.

Comment: But the image you mentioned can belong to a different convex polytope, not necessarily $\mathcal{M}$, right? If so, what could it be? My problem is not that the exponentially mapped image must lie in $\mathcal{M}$, rather could it be some convex polytope?

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, I misunderstood your comment. The image is not a convex polytope. It is not a convex set at all. I'll edit my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you say that the last statement $\notin f(\mathcal{M})$? Is it because $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ cannot be represented as $exp$ of some matrix $\in \mathcal{M}$? I am sorry if that sounds too silly, but I appreciate your clarification and time.

Comment: Yes, you can check that yourself, too.